# How can I perform a "printf string attack" using a buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

The code:

```
void doit()
{       
      system("/bin/sh");
      exit(0); 
}       

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       
    static int the_var;
    char buf[512];

    the_var = 20;

    strncpy (buf, argv[1], sizeof(buf) - 1);

    printf (buf);

    if (the_var != 20)
    {
            doit();
    } else {
            printf ("\nthe_var @ 0x%08x = %d 0x%08x\n", &the_var, the_var, the_var);
    }
}
```

Program is running with sticky bit (owner uid 0) all I have to do is to crack it and run the `/bin/sh` as the root.

I know how to crack the program with `fe`. buffer overflow and `strcpy` (shellcode), but don't how to to use 'format string attack' on this one.

As you can see, there is a `var the_var`, if it is not equal to 50 then shell is running (maybe try to change it somehow, some dirty magic?). Anyway, there is a `printf (buf)`

Answer (score 5):

You control `buf`. Pass `%x` format strings to dump the stack and `%n` to overwrite the object `the_var` in the stack. From your program if the object `the_var` is overwritten, the `doit` function will be called and `/bin/sh` will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it was simple.